# How to make progress bar in powershell while script is loading until it runs?

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

I've scripted a Powershell code and it works perfectly.

But there is a lot a of DB connections or downloading elements from the DB.

That's why when i run my script, it takes a while before the GUI form appears.

Is there someone who knows how to make a progress bar that appears when i execute my script and stop it when the GUI form appears ?

Thank you for your help,

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to check this.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/29/add-a-progress-bar-to-your-powershell-script.aspx

Comment: I don't run a service so i can not us this solution. My soft is a Powershell script that i've compiled with PowerGUI to an exe file. I run this exe file and then my Powershell application is loading but it just appears in task manager not in services.msc.

Comment: Oh.. I thought otherwise.. Let me check some more.

Comment: I've seen many posts to make a progress bar in Powershell but no one speaks about my problem ... Thank you for helping me !

Comment: Are you trying to write an interactive program or a service? No service should ever have a progress bar because there's no user interface.

Comment: Finally, i've didn't found how to run it and i've decided to code it in html/javascript.